# How to add element with props in react router V6

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/Cart" element={<Cart data />}>   
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Here I want to pass the element Cart ,but the Cart has props of the following type

```
export type CartItemtype = {
  id: number;
  category: string;
  description: string;
  image: string;
  price: string;
  title: string;
  amount: number;
}
```

data is an array of type CartItemtype[]
I am using react-router-dom V6

Below is App.tsx and Item.tsx file

```
import React from 'react';
import Page from './Page';
import Todo from './models/todo';
import FormSubmission from './FormSubmission';
import Registration from './Registration';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Type } from 'typescript';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { Wrapper, StyledButton } from './App.styles';
import Item from './Item/Item';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Cart from './Cart/Cart';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";


export type CartItemtype = {
  id: number;
  category: string;
  description: string;
  image: string;
  price: string;
  title: string;
  amount: number;
}

const getProducts = async (): Promise<CartItemtype[]> => {
  return await (await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")).json();
}


function App() {
  const [cartOpen, setCartOpen] = useState(false);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([] as CartItemtype[]);
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery<CartItemtype[]>('products', getProducts);
  //useQuery is a react hook
  console.log(data);
  const getTotalItems = (items: CartItemtype[]) => null;

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleClick = () => {
    navigate("/Cart");
  }
  if (error) return <div>Somethimg went wrong</div>;
  <Router>
    <Route path="/Cart" element={<Cart data />}>
    </Route>
  </Router>
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>Navigate To Cart</Button>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        {data?.map((item, key) => {
          return (

            <Grid item key={item.id} xs={12} sm={4}>
              <Item item={item} />
            </Grid>

          )
        })
        }
      </Grid>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
export default App;


import {CartItemtype} from '../App';
import {Wrapper} from './Item.styles';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

type itemProps={
    item:CartItemtype;
    // handleAddToCart:(clickedItem:CartItemtype)=>void;
}
const handleAddToCart = (clickedItem: CartItemtype) => null;

const Item:React.FC<itemProps>=({item})=>
{
return(
<Wrapper>
<img src={item.image} alt={item.title}></img>
<div>
<h3>{item.title}</h3>
<p>{item.description}</p>
<h3>${item.price}</h3>
</div>
<Button onClick={()=>handleAddToCart(item)}>Add To Cart</Button>
</Wrapper>
);
}

export default Item;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams):

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />   
</Router>
```

then in the Cart component:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"

const Cart = (props) => {
  const { id } = useParams()
}
export default Cart
```

If you're having issues navigating to the component try changing:

```
<Route path="/Cart" element={<Cart cartItems={cartItems} />}> </Route>
```

to:

```
<Route path="/cart" element={<Cart cartItems={cartItems} />}/>
```

Comment: I solved it using the below command.But I am not navigated to the Cart page eventhough my url is changing<Router>
    <Route path="/Cart" element={<Cart cartItems={cartItems} />}>
    </Route>
  </Router>

Comment: maybe due to you're calling `/Cart` instead of what's typically used with the lowercase version: `/cart`.

Comment: Thanks Darth for the help.I will try with your solution.

Comment: if it answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: No I am still facing issue with navigating to the Cart component

Comment: https://github.com/cynthia22ekm/React-Application-3